# Null pointer exception on setAdapter()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm attempting to create a custom ListView adapter (roughly based on [this tutorial](http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2011/12/building-a-custom-multi-line-listview-in-android/), but the example is simple enough I doubt you need to look at it).

**NewsEntriesAdapter.java**

```
public class NewsEntriesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<NewsEntries> newsEntriesArrayList;

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public NewsEntriesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsEntries> entries) {
        newsEntriesArrayList = entries;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return newsEntriesArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return newsEntriesArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_list_row_view,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtCityState = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cityState);
            holder.txtPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtName.setText(newsEntriesArrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtCityState.setText(newsEntriesArrayList.get(position)
                .getCityState());
        holder.txtPhone.setText(newsEntriesArrayList.get(position).getPhone());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtCityState;
        TextView txtPhone;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java (onCreate method)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<NewsEntries> results = new ArrayList<NewsEntries>();

    // I left the NewsEntries class out of this question; it's just a POJO with some get and set methods for Name, CityState, and Phone
    NewsEntries sr = new NewsEntries();
    sr.setName("Justin Schultz");
    sr.setCityState("San Francisco, CA");
    sr.setPhone("415-555-1234");
    results.add(sr);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    System.out.println(results.get(0).getName());

    lv.setAdapter(new NewsEntriesAdapter(this, results));
}
```

However, the `lv.setAdapter` line right above this crashes the app with a null pointer exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where does the `NullPointerException` happen? What is it that is null?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not setting any content in your `Activity`. There is no `setContentView` or `addContentView` call in your `onCreate`.

Hence, `findViewById` will not be able to find a view since there are **no** views at all, and will return `null`.

Comment: Thanks! Added `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to the top of `onCreate()` and `R.id.list` to `android.R.id.list`.